# required don't work for repeated field type in EventSubscriber

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, fosuserbundle

I created form `EditFormType` with code:

```
// ...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // ...
    $builder->addEventSubscriber(new UnsetReadOnlyForEmailField());
}
// ...
```

and `UnsetReadOnlyForEmailField`:

```
// ...
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData'
    );
}

public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();

    if ($data === null) {
        return;
    }

    if ($data->getId() === null) {
        $form->add(
            'plainPassword',
            'repeated',
            array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle', 'required' => true),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
            )
        );
    }
}
// ...
```

Unfortunately `required` for repeated field doesn't work, field is't required. Any suggestions? If I do it wrong, then please write to set the fields in the form are required or not, depending on the form to edit or add. On add form required, on edit form not required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in such way:

```
$form->add(
    'plainPassword',
    'repeated',
    array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
        'first_options' => array(
             'label' => 'form.password',
             'required' => true
        ),
        'second_options' => array(
            'label' => 'form.password_confirmation',
            'required' => true
         ),
        'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
    )
);
```

Comment: thx for answer, I found an error in `EditProfileType`, I had declaration of this field in two places, in `EditProfileType` and in `UnsetReadOnlyForEmailField`.